# User interactive Graph from DataGridView

Tags: c#, graph, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that displays information that is read from a txt file. My aim is to create a line graph for this data which displays DateTime for the X axis.

My aim is to create the graph so it shows the information from the Gridview onto the graph. The user can then select points on the graph that then show them specific info from that part of the data for example a row.

I am not sure which API to use for this:

I have tried using internal Chart functions for Visual Studio but I can not interact the selectable part onto the graphs I created.

If anyone has any advice on how to do this would be great.

Comment: _I can not interact the selectable part onto the graphs I created._ I don't understand. What graphics is it you want to generate? Can you post a link to an example image?

Comment: I want to create a line graph and then the user can select points on the graph and then view the data it is representing. For example small points on the line graph and you can hover over them and display data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems to have several parts. I'll try to help with each..

The last part in your question is solved like this:

Assuming you have a Chart with the DataPoints set and showing the line, you can use this:

```
 Series S = chart1.Series[0];  // short reference
 S.ToolTip = "#VALX{#.##}" +  " : " +  "#VALY1{#.##}";
```

to display the x- and y-values as tooltips in a format you like.

[image]

See [MSDN for a full list of keywords to use in referring to the DataPoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456687%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

If you want to display data that are not part of the `DataPoint`'s data you can instead create individual `ToolTips` for each `DataPoint` when you add it:

```
double dx = yourXValue;
double dy = yourYValue;
DataPoint dp = new DataPoint(dx, dy);
dp.ToolTip =  yourToolTip;
S.Points.Add(dp);
```

You will have to create the `ToolTip` readily formatted for each `DataPoint`!

If other parts are still open, please say so!

Comment: Okay that is fantastic! - Another point from the data that is in my GridView I managed to calculate averages which are displayed in a RichTextBox next to the GridView - How would I implement them into the tooltip of the point on the graph.

Comment: See the updated answer: You can create an individual `ToolTip` using all data you want to every `DataPoint`