# Chart, showing date/time with mouse over

Tags: c#

I am currently attempting to show the x,y values whenever I mouse over a point on the chart but for the x axis is in a date/time format, and I want to display the date/time instead of the actual pixel value.

What I am currently using is this following code for the mouse over event

```
private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var pos = e.Location;
        if (prevPosition.HasValue && pos == prevPosition.Value)
            return;
        tooltip.RemoveAll();
        prevPosition = pos;
        var results = chart1.HitTest(pos.X, pos.Y, false,
                                        ChartElementType.DataPoint);
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint)
            {
                var prop = result.Object as DataPoint;
                if (prop != null)
                {
                    var pointXPixel = result.ChartArea.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(prop.XValue);
                    var pointYPixel = result.ChartArea.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(prop.YValues[0]);

                    // check if the cursor is really close to the point (2 pixels around the point)
                    if (Math.Abs(pos.X - pointXPixel) < 2 &&
                        Math.Abs(pos.Y - pointYPixel) < 2)
                    {
                        tooltip.Show("X=" + prop.XValue + ", Y=" + prop.YValues[0], this.chart1,
                                        pos.X, pos.Y - 15);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In terms of the formatting of the x axis goes, I have this

```
  chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MMM.dd.yyyy HH:mm:ss";
  chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
```

I was wondering if there was a simple way to convert the point into a date/time value.

Thank you

Comment: Probably you should note which platform you are targeting.

Comment: I suggest to consider using datapoint tooltips. See [here for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29895445/c-sharp-user-interactive-graph-from-datagridview/29939620?s=4|0.2516#29939620). The data values are right there but do make sure they are __really datetime__ values if you want to format them as such.  Quite often they are only strings. You may want to show the code that adds them..or at least check the X-Values of the Points!!